# Redirect certain 404 pages to parent page

Tags: redirect, 404-error

I'm getting a lot of "Not found (404)" errors in Google Search Console when users delete listings on my website.

Does anyone know if it's possible to redirect certain 404 pages automatically for example https://www.mysite.co.uk/used-cars/volkswagen/passat/11071269/ to https://www.mysite.co.uk/used-cars/

I would still like 404 pages to work but only redirect for the above formats.

Thanks

Comment: note that redirects themselves can have SEO consequences, depending on how you redirect you might find it thinks you haven't deleted that car but have actually moved the page to `/used-cars` which isn't good. You also have a major UX problem that users may then revisit the original URL thinking they didn't type it in right or think that your site is misbehaving. Have you considered instead telling users the car isn't available anymore and providing a link to the used cars site? That way Google is happy, your users understand the car isn't available, and you get an upsell to your used cars page

Comment: Yes, I also think this sounds like a good idea. If I create a dedicated page for sold cars, do you know how I can redirect the sold cars to this page?

Comment: redirecting to a dedicated page that says the car was deleted will have all the same SEO downsides as your original plan. Why not put the message directly on the 404 page and have zero redirects? Remember that 404's need to be super light weight and will probably be cached, and the last thing you want is for your "redirected page" to show up in google search results. Imagine hundreds of entries in a search that all read "This car was sold" in the title and excerpt coupled with a duplicate content penalty. A real 404 page doesn't do that. Redirection is very bad.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, my concern is that I have thousands of "Soft 404" errors in Google Search Console so as much as that sounds like a good idea, it won't stop the warnings in GSC. Do you have any other ideas? or do you think I'm safe to ignore all the Soft 404 warnings?

Comment: you'd need to ask a Google SEO specialist about that